# PHP Regex match file or directory

Tags: php, regex

Given a URL path, I am attempting to create a regular expression to match if the path points to a directory, and to not match if it points to file extensions .php, .js, .html, .htm, etc.

Match:

```
/www/site/path/ny/
```

Match:

```
/www/news/state.208/ii
```

Do not match:

```
/www/news/index.php
```

Do not match:

```
/www/site/fr/post.py
```

Here is my regex that I've been working with:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9/_\-]*[^/])$
```

This regex does what I want, but it isn't precise enough. It assumes it is a path to a file and stops matching whenever it comes across a ".", but I need to consider the possibility that the directory name contains a ".", like in the example above.

I also tried using negative look behinds with no luck:

```
^(.(?!\.php)|(?!\.htm?l)|(?!\.js))$
```

Comment: What do you mean by *a period* ?

Comment: A period is a 'full stop' or '.'

Comment: you haven't specified what you're using this for, but PHP has lots of built in functions in this area -- php's `file_exists()`, `is_dir()`, `pathinfo()`, `basename()`, and other functions may be more appropriate than complex regex here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this tiny one:

```
^.*/[^\.]*$
```

edit:

```
^.*/((?!\.js|\.php|\.html).)*$
```

replace or extend with the extensions you want to ignore.

Comment: This almost works, except it wouldn't match the directory: "/www/ww.news4".

Comment: @deraad: see edit then. as you tell you want "file extensions" to be ignored, the only way to achieve it with a regex is to define a list of unwanted extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using PHP, you might want to try [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) instead:

```
$parts = pathinfo('/www/site/path/file.php');
```

In this case `$parts['extension']` will exist, in other cases it will not.

Comment: Good idea, except I need this to be a regex for a variety of reasons

Comment: @deraad - it might help you with getting helpful answers if you explain those 'variety of reasons'. From what you've said so far, regex doesn't sound like the appropriate solution.

Comment: @SDC I need it in regex form because it will go not only in a PHP function, but in an htaccess file as well. If I were only using this in my PHP script, I would use the PHP functions like pathinfo()

Answer (score 1):

To simplify your question, you are looking for a string starting with /, and the last segment doesn't have a extension:

```
[\/]{0,1}.*\/[^\.]*.{1}$
```

Edit:

This works for all your examples:

```
^(.*\/){0,1}[^\.]*.{1}$
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily HAVE to start with a '/'. It may or may not. To simplify it should look for strings containing: a-zA-Z0-9/_\.-  and does not end in a file extension.

Comment: Thanks for editing that, but it appears to still be matching "www/fr/this.php", I'm trying to get it to not match when there is a file extension at the end.